Store an array of non-Codable structures in Swift
I want to store an array of non-Codable structures (= HabitConfiguration()) in UserDefaults.
Here is my attempt which consists in placing in a "dictionary" the variables of this structure before storing it in UserDefaults. There is no explicit error in my code but executing it crashes my application.
The model of structures to save in an array (not compliant to Codable):
struct HabitConfiguration {
    var name: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
    var appearance: String = "planet"
    var planetColor: Color = Color("PlanetColor1")
    var planetHasRing: Bool = false
    var planetRingStyle = PlanetRingStyle()
    var planetRotation: Double = 0
    var emoji: String = ""
    var repetitionType: RepetitionType = .unique(date: [UniqueDate(day: 1, month: 1, time: Time(hours: 12, minutes: 0))])
}

Additional code needed for the previous structure:
struct PlanetRingStyle {
    var lineWidth: Double = 5
    var lineCap: CGLineCap = .round
    var dash: [CGFloat] = [1]
}

enum RepetitionType {
    case daily(time: Time)
    case weekly(days: Days, time: Time)
    case monthly(dates: DaysNumbers, time: Time)
    case unique(date: [UniqueDate])
}

extension RepetitionType {
    var isDaily: Bool {
        if case .daily = self { return true }
        return false
    }
    var isWeekly: Bool {
        if case .weekly = self { return true }
        return false
    }
    var isMonthly: Bool {
        if case .monthly = self { return true }
        return false
    }
    var isUnique: Bool {
        if case .unique = self { return true }
        return false
    }
}

"Dictionary" of structure values:
extension HabitConfiguration {
    func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
        "name": name,
        "description": description,
        "appearance": appearance,
        "planetColor": planetColor.description,
        "planetHasRing": planetHasRing,
        "planetRingStyle": planetRingStyle,
        "planetRotation": planetRotation,
        "emoji": emoji,
        "repetitionType": repetitionType
        ]
    }

    init?(from dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard
        let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
        let description = dictionary["description"] as? String,
        let appearance = dictionary["appearance"] as? String,
        let planetColorDescription = dictionary["planetColor"] as? String,
        let planetHasRing = dictionary["planetHasRing"] as? Bool,
        let planetRingStyle = dictionary["planetRingStyle"] as? Int,
        let planetRotation = dictionary["planetRotation"] as? Double,
        let emoji = dictionary["emoji"] as? String,
        let repetitionType = dictionary["repetitionType"] as? RepetitionType
        else {
            return nil
        }

        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.appearance = appearance
        self.planetColor = Color(planetColorDescription)
        self.planetHasRing = planetHasRing
        self.planetRingStyle = PlanetRingStyle(lineWidth: 0, lineCap: .round, dash: [0])
        self.planetRotation = planetRotation
        self.emoji = emoji
        self.repetitionType = repetitionType
    }
}

Read and write the array stored in UserDefaults:
struct HabitsList {
    private let habitsKey = "habitsList"

    func loadHabits() -> [HabitConfiguration] {
        guard let savedHabits = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: habitsKey) as? [[String: Any]] else {
            return [] 
        }
        return savedHabits.compactMap { HabitConfiguration(from: $0) }
    }

    func saveHabits(_ habits: [HabitConfiguration]) {
        let habitDictionaries = habits.map { $0.toDictionary() }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(habitDictionaries, forKey: habitsKey)
    }

    func habitsList() -> Binding<[HabitConfiguration]> {
        Binding(
            get: { self.loadHabits() },
            set: { self.saveHabits($0) }
        )
    }
}


The answer is probably "don't do that". UserDefaults isn't intended for that kind of data storage. But, even if you use CoreData/SwiftData you are going to need to refactor to use a struct instead of an enum with associated values

If you want to store a dictionary in UserDefaults you can only use supported (Codable) types and your RepetitionType isn't one of them.

I added (Codable) compliance (with some changes to the structures) to store in UserDefaults.

UserDefaults is not the thing to use here. The correct thing to use is either a local CoreData Store or using a custom JSON File (requires Codable compliance).
Codable compliance is also really easy to add to an existing struct.
The hurdle you are probably facing there is adding support for Color, other than that you can just mark the struct PlanetRingStyle and enum RepititionType as well as the other structs/enums used as Codable as well and it should be smooth sailing from there.
If you are already implementing Codable compliance you could also use @AppStorage
